# Why is Layer::drawWithOpenGL never called?

Tags: android, surfaceflinger

I'm trying to understand Android rendering code a little better. So I add some logging in Layer::drawWithOpenGL() function, which is part of SurfaceFlinger. But it seems, it never gets called. Can someone shed light on why this is the case?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably performing composition with overlays instead.  See the [architecture overview](https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/arch-sf-hwc.html) for more info.

You can disable overlays (on a rooted device) with `adb shell service call SurfaceFlinger 1008 i32 1`.